# Ignoring other tables when centralizing one

Tags: html, html-table, alignment, center

I recently learned HTML and I am having some troubles centering a table. Since I have two tables in my project that are in the same height, I made one table aligned to the left and the other one I wanted to align to the center. Since they are at the same vertical position, the first table is fine, but the second table is centered according to the distance from the right of the 1st table and the right of the website.

I wanted to know how I could center the second table, ignoring the first one, in a way that it is centered according to the website center and not according to the table and the website center.

The current code is something like this:

```
<table align="left" width="300" bgcolor="#454545">
    <tr height="65" bgcolor="565656" style="border-radius: 2%">
        <td><center><img src="facebookLogo.png" width="65" height="65"></center></td>
        <td><a href="https://www.facebook.com/somepagehere"><font size="4" color="#FFFFFF">&nbsp; Like our page at Facebook!</font></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="65" bgcolor="565656" style="border-radius: 2%">
        <td><center><img src="twitterLogo.png" width="65" height="65"></center></td>
        <td><a href="https://www.twitter.com/someaccouthere"><font size="4" color="#FFFFFF">&nbsp; Follow us at Twitter!</font></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="65" bgcolor="565656" style="border-radius: 2%">
        <td><center><img src="youtubeLogo.png" width="65" height="65"></center></td>
        <td><a href="https://www.youtube.com/someaccouthere"><font size="4" color="#FFFFFF">&nbsp; Check us on Youtube!</font></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="20">
    </tr>
</table>

<table width="400" height="200" bgcolor="#000000" align="center">
    <tr></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: jsFiddle, for anyone interested: http://jsfiddle.net/qj35U/

Comment: Note that if you center the second table the way you want, then it might overlap with the first one.

Comment: Nope, the width of the first and the second table fits very well on the screen without overlapsing each other.

Comment: But anyways, do you know how to do that?

Comment: No, I'm stumped. You may want to look into absolute positioning.

Answer (score 1):

Some notes:

- Tables should only be used for tabular data. It's not the case.
- You should separate the content and presentation.

  - That's why `<font>`, `<center>` and `bgcolor` were deprecated. Don't use them anymore.
- As @rvighne said, tables could overlap. Maybe you have a very wide screen, but that doesn't mean everyone has.

See a [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/qj35U/1/)

HTML:

```
<ul id="social">
    <li>
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/somepagehere">
            <img src="facebookLogo.png" width="65" height="65" />
            Like our page at Facebook!
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="https://www.twitter.com/someaccouthere">
            <img src="twitterLogo.png" width="65" height="65" />
            Follow us at Twitter!
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/someaccouthere">
            <img src="youtubeLogo.png" width="65" height="65" />
            Check us on Youtube!
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div id="other">
    Foo bar
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#social {
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #565656;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
#social img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#social a {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
}

#other {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #ffc;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it might take a bit time to understand what is going on though. Anyways, thanks.